# What is the correct callback signature for a function called using ctypes in python?

Tags: python, callback, ctypes, stdcall

I have to define a callback function in Python, one that will be called from a DLL.

```
BOOL setCallback (LONG nPort, void ( _stdcall *pFileRefDone) (DWORD nPort, DWORD nUser), DWORD nUser);
```

I tried this code, that seems to work in Python 2.5 but with Python 2.7 it crashes and I assume I did something wrong.

```
import ctypes, ctypes.wintypes
from ctypes.wintypes import DWORD

def cbFunc(port, user_data):
        print "Hurrah!"

CB_Func = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE(None, DWORD, DWORD)

mydll.setCallback(ctypes.c_long(0), CB_Func(cbFunc), DWORD(0))
```

Where is the mistake?

Note: The platform is running on 32bit only (both Windows and Python). The DLL loads successfully and also other functions from inside do work just fine while called from Python.

A full sample code that reproduces this is available at https://github.com/ssbarnea/pyHikvision - just run Video.py under py25 and py27.

Comment: The function pointer given in the first line points to a function returning `void`, not `void*`.

Comment: In case my first comment wasn't clear enough:  This is in contradiction to the return type declaration of your `WINFUNCTYPE`, which is `c_void_p`.

Comment: Use `None` to indicate the return type `void`. Who's Steven, btw? :)

Comment: You don't need to use `ctypes.py_object(self)` to gain access to `self` in your callback. We already told you that in your previous question. However, you seem set on doing it your way. That's up to you. It's far from obvious to me that `self` can reliably be cast to a 32 bit int. Also, is your Python 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: I can't see anything wrong there. Does `setCallback` actually result in the callback being invoked, or does that happen at some later time.

Comment: Is `cbFunc` at module scope? Your code is clearly incomplete since there is a `self` there. I'm wondering if `cbFunc` is a local function that goes out of scope when it's enclosing function ends. Try with `cbFunc` at module scope.

Comment: OOps, I just replaced it with 0. BTW, I will remove my former comments as they are not useful anymore.

Comment: Is `setCallback` declared as `stdcall`. Looks like `cdecl` to me.

Comment: For the signature take a look at https://github.com/ssbarnea/pyHikvision/blob/master/PlayM4.h#L276 - also here you can find all the code the reproduces this behaviour. Just runt the Video.py with py27 and you'll see the crash, running it with py25 will work.

Comment: If I try to load the DLL with CDLL() it will fail to call the functions, so WinDLL() is correct. If there is something wrong is something related to the calling convention of for the callback. BTW, if I define the callback with CFUNCTYPE() it will always crash.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the context of [Video class](https://github.com/ssbarnea/pyHikvision/blob/master/Video.py#L86) using a nested function:

```
class Video(object):

    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.__cbFileRefDone = []

    def open(self, filename):
        @WINFUNCTYPE(None, DWORD, DWORD)
        def cbFileRefDone(port, user_data):
            print "File indexed.", filename
        self.__cbFileRefDone.append(cbFileRefDone) # save reference

        if not self.hsdk.PlayM4_SetFileRefCallBack(
            c_long(self.port), cbFileRefDone, DWORD(0)):
            logging.error("Unable to set callback for indexing")
            return False
```

It is somewhat ugly but a more natural variant fails with TypeError during callback:

```
#XXX this won't work
@WINFUNCTYPE(None, DWORD, DWORD)
def cbFileRefDone(self, port, user_data):
    print "File indexed."
```

To fix that a special function descriptor could be created:

```
def method(prototype):
    class MethodDescriptor(object):
        def __init__(self, func):
            self.func = func
            self.bound_funcs = {} # hold on to references to prevent gc
        def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
            assert obj is not None # always require an instance
            try: return self.bound_funcs[obj,type]
            except KeyError:
                ret = self.bound_funcs[obj,type] = prototype(
                    self.func.__get__(obj, type))
                return ret
    return MethodDescriptor
```

Usage:

```
class Video(object):

    @method(WINFUNCTYPE(None, DWORD, DWORD))
    def cbFileRefDone(self, port, user_data):
        print "File indexed."

    def open(self, filename):
        # ...
        self.hsdk.PlayM4_SetFileRefCallBack(
            c_long(self.port), self.cbFileRefDone, DWORD(0))
```

Additionally MethodDescriptor saves references to C functions to prevent them being garbage collected.

Comment: I wasn't aware that I can have a member function as a C-callback function without having to care about the self parameter. This is really cool. If you don't mind I will remove the code that doesn't work from your response to make it easier to read.

Comment: @sorin: the first example actually works (if you add `self.__cbFileRefDone = []` in the `__init__()` It is implied from the usage: `self__cbFileRefDone.append()`.). It just uses a nested function instead of a method. And it is much simpler to understand by people who don't know about descriptors. Additionally it allows to use local to the `open()` method data. The drawback is that it creates a new function object on each call to `open()` (the method approach creates a single callback per object, type pair).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, since a decorator is just a function that returns a function, you can just use the callback type as the decorator.  See my updated answer.

Comment: @Mark Tolonen: `winfunctype()` doesn't work as a decorator for method functions. I've rollbacked the edit by @sorin of my answer that removed the example.

Answer (score 4):

Your CB_Func(cbFunc) parameter gets garbage-collected right after the setCallback function.  That object has to persist as long as the callback can be called ([15.17.1.17. Callback functions](http://docs.python.org/library/ctypes.html?highlight=ctypes#callback-functions), last paragraph).  Assign it to a variable and keep it around.  Here's my working example:

#### DLL

```
typedef unsigned int DWORD;
typedef long LONG;
typedef int BOOL;
#define TRUE  1
#define FALSE 0

typedef void (__stdcall *CALLBACK)(DWORD,DWORD);

CALLBACK g_callback = 0;
DWORD g_port = 0;
DWORD g_user = 0;

BOOL __declspec(dllexport) setCallback (LONG nPort, CALLBACK callback, DWORD nUser)
{
    g_callback = callback;
    g_port = nPort;
    g_user = nUser;
    return TRUE;
}

void __declspec(dllexport) Fire()
{
    if(g_callback)
        g_callback(g_port,g_user);
}
```

#### Failing Script

```
from ctypes import *

def cb_func(port,user):
    print port,user

x = CDLL('x')
CALLBACK = WINFUNCTYPE(None,c_uint,c_uint)
#cbfunc = CALLBACK(cb_func)
x.setCallback(1,CALLBACK(cb_func),2)
x.Fire()
```

#### Passing Script

```
from ctypes import *

def cb_func(port,user):
    print port,user

x = CDLL('x')
CALLBACK = WINFUNCTYPE(None,c_uint,c_uint)
cbfunc = CALLBACK(cb_func)
x.setCallback(1,cbfunc,2)
x.Fire()
```

**Edit**: Also, since `CALLBACK` is a function returning a function, it can be used as a decorator for the Python callback, eliminating problem of the callback going out of scope:

```
from ctypes import * 

CALLBACK = WINFUNCTYPE(None,c_uint,c_uint) 

@CALLBACK
def cb_func(port,user): 
    print port,user 

x = CDLL('x') 
x.setCallback(1,cb_func,2) 
x.Fire()
```